# Getting the incorrect result while initializing the php variable to java script variable

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have a php page home.php and in this I have a php variable `$disableCreate = 'true';` . Please see the below code.

```
<?php

 ob_start();
 include_once("app_header.php");
 $disableVar = 'true';    

 //below code to show the home page template
 $htmlrenderObj = Htmlrender::getObj();          
 $template_path  = $htmlrenderObj->app_home_template_path."app_home.html";
 $template       = $htmlrenderObj->return_file_content($template_path);
 ob_end_flush(); 
 include_once("app_footer.php");
?>
```

Now in the java script section I'm trying to access that variable and assign it to java script variable.

```
<script>
 var xmlHttp = getAjaxObj();

 var myJsVar = "<?php echo $disableVar; ?>";
 var myJsVar2 = "<?php echo json_encode($disableVar); ?>";
 var myJsVar3 = "<?=$disableVar?>";
 var myJsVar4 = "$disableVar";

 console.log("$$$$$$$$ myJsVar is:"+myJsVar);
 console.log("$$$$$$$$ myJsVar is:"+myJsVar2);
 console.log("$$$$$$$$ myJsVar is:"+myJsVar3);
 console.log("$$$$$$$$ myJsVar is:"+myJsVar4);

</script>
```

I tried different ways to initialize my java script variable with php variable. But not get the desired output. Please see the below screenshot for reference.

[image]

Please help me.

Comment: remove the php code form the quotes, for example: var myJsVar3 = <?=$disableVar; ?> and don't forget to close php line with ;

Comment: From the looks of it, "in the java script section" actually means "a separate javascript file which does not run through PHP".

Comment: Hi zippax, I have edited my code as you suggested and getting Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<' error.

Comment: Hi mario, it is not a separate javascript file. It is in the same html file under <script> tag.